# Assembler code in C for Raspberry

Tags: c, loops, assembly, raspberry-pi

I tried to make a loop to detect HIGH level on GPIO17 of raspberry pi.
I did it in c, but it turned out that it counts to slow therefore I tried to make this loop in asm but it does not work properly.

Here is the asm part:

```
asm volatile(

"mov r0,#17;"
"ldr r1,=0x20200000;"
"mov r4,#1;"
"loop: ldr r2,[r1,#34];"
"lsr r2,r2,r0;"
"and r3,r2,#1;"
"cmp r4,r3;"
"bne loop;"
);
```

Comment: Are you running bare metal or on linux?

Comment: why not just make this an asm function, why inline?  if you inline you probably need to tell the compiler about everything you are doing (just makeing it an asm function is much easier).

Comment: sorry, i didnt get about asm function) I thought it is what I have) May you give me a short axample?) I am using c code with wiringPI and bcm2835 lib linked + this assembler part. Only the lines with "loop" causes the problem. Many thanks.

Comment: What exactly led you to believe that the C loop was too slow? Did you disassemble it and compared? Did you turn on optimizations? Do you generate thumb or arm code? (In the first case, your assembly is invalid). Please provide more information, including what error you encountered and source code of the associated C code.

Comment: if running on linux then you cant simply use that physical address 0x20200000 directly you need to use mmap or something to give you a virtual address from application space that is mapped to the physical.  Are you getting a crash when you do it this way?  At least in general you cant do this...

Comment: asm ( ); is inline assembly I assume in C that is different than writing assembly and assembling it into an object.  In particular r4 but likely all the registers you are using you need to declare in the inline assembly in order to not screw up the code that surrounds it.  Please include more code and disassemble your binary and include the code above plus some around it so we can see if the code above is causing register conflicts.